# Excel 2010 graph color fomating without VBA -connecting to Cube (SSAS)

Tags: excel, excel-2010, olap-cube, vba

We have peculiar problem.  We are connecting to a cube (MS SSAS) to fetch data for a dashboard which is showing set of graphs (bar,line charts).  We need to depict different colors based on data obtained from cube( we are making use of slicers, as dashboard needs to dynamic based on parameters selected).  We have used VBA to depict the color changes in graphs, however VBA doesn't work when used in Excel Services.  We are using Excel 2010 and we have observed that in Excel 2010, Conditional formatting icon is disabled when connected to cube.  We would appreciate if you could provide us pointers on the same.

Our problem statement is to change colors in Excel 2010 without using VBA for set of graphs (bar and line) which is fetching data from a cube.   Pointers on this would really help, as we are struck.

Comment: You don't need to include signature in your post - your user card is added automatically. Read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) for more details.